# Facebook Canvas doesn't load

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm trying to create a Facebook app using their quick setup. But when I load it in Facebook there's nothing to show. If I access the link where is my index.html then I can see the content.

This is the code from index.html.  What else do I need or what am I doing wrong? All it should show is just a simple "Hello World".

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '715546978567965',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.3'
    });

    // ADD ADDITIONAL FACEBOOK CODE HERE

    // Place following code after FB.init call.

function onLogin(response) {
  if (response.status == 'connected') {
    FB.api('/me?fields=first_name', function(data) {
      var welcomeBlock = document.getElementById('fb-welcome');
      welcomeBlock.innerHTML = 'Hello, ' + data.first_name + '!';
    });
  }
}

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  // Check login status on load, and if the user is
  // already logged in, go directly to the welcome message.
  if (response.status == 'connected') {
    onLogin(response);
  } else {
    // Otherwise, show Login dialog first.
    FB.login(function(response) {
      onLogin(response);
    }, {scope: 'user_friends, email'});
  }
});


  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<h1 id="fb-welcome"></h1>

<div class="title">Hello World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How did you configure canvas platform in your app settings? Do you have a secure canvas URL starting with `https://` specified? You _need_ HTTPS for canvas apps, otherwise the browser will block it, because the parent page was loaded via HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is a bit messy, you include the facebook js not via https, but via http. usually its just

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
```

This way it gets loaded by the same protocoll the parent page was called.
I just did basically the same you did, but it works for me.

Try copy&pasterino this:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1 id="fb-welcome"></h1>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '715546978567965',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.3'
    });

    // ADD ADDITIONAL FACEBOOK CODE HERE

    // Place following code after FB.init call.

    function onLogin(response) {
      if (response.status == 'connected') {
        FB.api('/me?fields=first_name', function(data) {
          var welcomeBlock = document.getElementById('fb-welcome');
          welcomeBlock.innerHTML = 'Hello, ' + data.first_name + '!';
        });
      }
    }

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      // Check login status on load, and if the user is
      // already logged in, go directly to the welcome message.
      if (response.status == 'connected') {
        onLogin(response);
      } else {
        // Otherwise, show Login dialog first.
        FB.login(function(response) {
          onLogin(response);
        }, {scope: 'user_friends, email'});
      }
    });

  };


  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<h1 id="fb-welcome"></h1>

<div class="title">Hello World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And make sure, as CBroe mentioned in the comment, that your server is reachable via https, or this will fail.